How can I fInd a record in NeDB / NestDB where the col value is a part of a string
I have found this solution for a MySQL DB
SQL - Query to find if a string contains part of the value in Column
but I need something similar for NestDB (NodeJS / Javascript)
or is this way not really slower?
arData.find(({ strUrlPart}) => strUrl.indexOf(strUrlPart) != -1); 
thx
